# How to share same post to multiple site in wordpress?

Tags: posts, multisite, blog

We are developing WordPress with multiple site. We need to share some posts to more than one site. We need to save post in more than one sites with a single click.

I have searched in Google, but I can't get any tutorial for that.

Comment: A bit off-topic but wouldn't that be considered as duplicate content and bad for SEO?

Comment: @SledgeHammer No that's syndicated content an not necessarily bad for SEO

Answer (score 2):

You can use the function [`switch_to_blog()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/switch_to_blog) for this

```
$other_id = 1234 // the id of the other blog to save the post to
switch_to_blog($other_id);
$my_post = array(
  'post_title'    => $post_title,
  'post_content'  => $post_content,
  'post_status'   => 'publish',
  'post_author'   => $post_author,
  );

// Insert the post into the database
wp_insert_post( $my_post );

restore_current_blog();
```

There is a pitfall if you execute this code on the `save_post` hook, because `wp_insert_post` also calls `save_post` and you end up in an infinite loop. [This post on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18690757) gives a solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

Author of [Broadcast](https://wordpress.org/plugins/threewp-broadcast/) here.

Seeing as I have quite a bit of experience with multiposting, and all it's associated problems, I'd suggest you let an experienced plugin take care of post sharing.

Using the [API](https://broadcast.plainviewplugins.com/doc/developer-api/) you can broadcast out the post to however many networked blogs you want. It will take care of all of the copying of attachments (yeah, attachments have different URLs and IDs on each blog) for you.

Here's how to broadcast post 123 to several blogs:

```
ThreeWP_Broadcast()->api()->broadcast_children( 123, [ 10, 11, 12 ] );
```

The above will also link the posts together, so when you update post 123, all of the children will be updated also.

Comment: Can I instead of broadcasting a published post, send a draft to be published in other websites?

Comment: Sure. Just broadcast the draft in that case. The posts don't have to be any particular status.

Comment: I see. So the destination site would receive the draft in whichever status it is?

Comment: The destination site would receive the **post** in whichever status it is, yes.